"Elementary" $L^2$ inequality for combination of compactly supported functions
I am reading the paper Ondelettes et poids du Muckenhoupt by Lemarié and, at some point, he needs to prove a certain operator is bounded in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ to apply weighted inequalities theory. The $L^2$ bound is supposed to be "elementary" due to an inequality that I don't really get. The setup is the following. Let $\omega$ be a $C^\infty$ function supported in $[-1,2]$ (I suppose the argument should work for any compactly supported function). Let $\omega_{j,k}=2^{j/2}\omega(2^jx-k)$. We want to prove the inequality
$$\left\|\sum_{j,k\in\mathbb Z} \lambda_{j,k}\omega_{j,k}\right\|^2_{L^2}\lesssim\sum_{j,k}|\lambda_{j,k}|^2.$$ Here $\lambda_{j,k}$ are just some coefficients. If you want, you may assume they are square summable, but the inequality is otherwise trivial. As said, the inequality is supposed to be elementary, but I am struggling to prove it. I have tried Hölder and also trying to bound the sum using the intersection of supports of $\omega_{j,k}$. Mind that, for a fixed $j$ and $x$, thereare at most $3$ values of $k$ for which $\omega_{j,k}(x)\neq0$. However, this does not really get me anywhere. What am I missing?

Perhaps it is possible to apply:  if we have a sequence of elements $u_n$ in a Hilbert space such that $$\sum_{n,m=1}^\infty |\langle u_n,u_m\rangle|^2<\infty$$ then $$\left |\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_nu_n\right |^2\le C\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\lambda_n|^2$$

@Ryszard Szwarc I think this should work. Why is it the case?

$$\left |\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_nu_n\right |^2 \leq \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left| \lambda_n\right| |u_n|\right)^2 \leq \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left| \lambda_n\right|^2\right)\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty  |u_n|^2\right)$$ The first inequality is the triangle inequality, the second one is Cauchy-Schwarz.

I'm more intrigued by something else: Are you not missing a hypothesis on $\omega$? Specifically, shouldn't $\omega$ be a wavelet (not the scaling function), so that only a finite number of $\langle \omega_{j,k} , \omega_{p, q}\rangle = 0$ when $j\neq p$ (across scales)? For instance, if $\omega$ is a the indicator of $(0, 1)$, summing across scales $j$ would make the series diverge, no?

@Stefan Lafon actually, this is exactly what was worrying me, but $\omega$ is not a wavelet. You can check page 16 in the article (142 in the magazine numbering) to see how he defines $\omega$. However, I think one can do the argument with the mother wavelet $\psi$ instead of $\omega$ and everything works...
